How do I use the completionHandler(.defer) in the ShieldActionExtension?
So basically I found this from a WWDC video for Screen Time API:
"The response can either be to close the shielded application or defer action and redraw the shield configuration.
The ability to defer action in the shield is very powerful because it gives the shield the chance to update its appearance while it waits for a signal on how to proceed.
For instance, it can be used to indicate that the shield is waiting for a guardian's action when the child taps Ask for Access here."
My goal is to do the same as the example but guide the user from the Shield Configuration to my own app and then let the user hit a button to let the user access the specific app. However I just need help with the button telling the awaiting shield that the app can be accessed. The below code is also from the WWDC video:
import ManagedSettings

class MyShieldActionExtension: ShieldActionHandler {
    override func handle(
        action: ShieldAction,
        for application: Application,
        completionHandler: @escaping (ShieldActionResponse) -> Void
    ) {
        switch action {
        case .primaryButtonPressed:
            completionHandler(.defer)
        case .secondaryButtonPressed:
            completionHandler(.close)
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}


I forgot to add that it's just impossible to find anything relevant. There is pretty much no documentation.

You would need to add additional code into the primaryButtonPressed case to take whatever action is required to handle the deferred case. In your case it would probably be to save the application token in your model so that when the SheildConfigurationProvider provides the sheildmfor this token you can return the appropriate config. E.g you can show whatever instructions you want the user to follow and change your first button title to "cancel" instead of "request"

@Paulw11 thanks for your answer! However I find it pretty hard to put that in code. Could you please comment some code snippets so I can understand the system of .defer a bit better?

It's hard to provide code because I don't know what your data model is, but in the primaryButtonPressed case you would have something like myModel.setState(application, .accessRequested) and then in your ShieldConfigurationProvider you would have if myModel.stateFor(application) == .accessRequest {... and configure the UI to indicate that access has been requested for this app
